# Pandas floating point issue with cumsum and division

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point-precision

I've ranked the total sales (TOTAL_2012) in descending order and am trying to get the list of groups to have roughly 25% of the sales thus tier 1 group is grossing the most sales/company.

```
sales['PERCENT_2012'] = sales['TOTAL_2012'] / sales['TOTAL_2012'].sum() 
sales['CUM_PERCENT_2012'] = sales['PERCENT_2012'].cumsum()
```

The problem is the CUM_PERCENT_2012 is larger than 100% or 1.00 with values such as 1.0000004 so I know it's a floating point issue, is there a way to enforce precision/round to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add .round():

```
sales['PERCENT_2012'] = sales['TOTAL_2012'] / sales['TOTAL_2012'].sum() 
sales['CUM_PERCENT_2012'] = sales['PERCENT_2012'].cumsum().round(2)
```

This actually rounds the data before adding it to the column. You can also use np.round(df) to round the data only for presenting/visualizing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display it sensibly, why not just run

```
pd.set_option('precision',3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `format()` on your result.

```
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(13.949999999999999)
'13.95'
```

For more information see [Python - String - Format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).